# How to implement a method for changing font color in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, objective-c, xcode

In my app i have a UIWebView having a content from file (HTML)

im wondering if there is any way to let the user changing the font color form 5 colors or something like that

Any way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to change it from the app (objective-c) or the html?

You could create a javascript function inside your html file which changes the font (by changing a class on the body tag for example).

If you want to change it from the app you can call the function with:

`[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"changeColor('red')"];`

---

something like this should work.

**CSS**

```
.red{
   color:#f00;
}
.green{
   color:#0f0;
}
.blue{
   color:#00f;
}
```

**JS**

```
function changeColor(colorClass){ // red, green or blue
    document.body.className = colorClass; 
}
```

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/mMhwC/

Comment: My problem is with implementing a method using objective c controlling javascript code

Comment: @Mutawe what problem do you have exactly? i wrote an example on how to call a javascript function from objective c in my answer.

Comment: i know how to call javascript function

but how to implement a function to change colors from 5 or 6 colors